# Inherited the Garden - Workflow Priority

Tags: pest-control, weed-control, lawn-repair

So I've inherited a large garden and now liable for any environmental issues with overgrowth... Is there a specific workflow to go off? Simply cutting back overgrowth and plucking weeds from between flags seems to be ineffective...

After a few years I realised more effort is required to control the garden eco-system. I now have knowledge that I have an abundance of weeds such as horsetails, ivy, creeping thistle. There are anthills all over and a growing tree. It seems my prior efforts may have affected the eco-system and created the conditions for undesirables.

Where should I start to attempt to turn the garden green with grass again?

Comment: The question is a bit broad. Any effort to help desirable helps weeds, too. Doesn't mean we did something wrong. What flags are part of the garden?

Comment: Vague. Entirely too vague. Start by pulling the weeds. Repeat (for a *long* time, frequently, with horsetail.)

Comment: Hi Steve, please add pictures and be more specific and we can reopen